# Excel VBA minverse

Tags: excel, vba

When I have defined matrix as `Dim M(1 To 6, 1 To 6)` I can easily use function `Application.WorksheetFunction.Minverse(M)`
But if I want to use dynamic array `Dim M()` and later using `Redim K(6,6)` I get an error "Runtime Error '1004' Unable to get minverse property of the WorksheetFunction class".

Am I doing something wrong or it is not possible to get matrix inverse using Minverse on a dynamic array?

Comment: Show relevant code. Please give a [mcve].

Comment: Why would you `ReDim` a variable called `K` if you declare your dynamic array with `Dim M`?  Surely you need to use the correct variable name.

Comment: Thank you for your replay! It is a typing error, i actually was using ReDim with variable M.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick test:

```
Sub test()
    Dim M As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    ReDim M(1 To 2, 1 To 2) As Double
    M(1, 1) = 5
    M(1, 2) = 5
    M(2, 2) = 3
    M = Application.WorksheetFunction.MInverse(M)
    For i = 1 To 2
        For j = 1 To 2
            Debug.Print M(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i           
End Sub
```

Output:

```
 0.2 
-0.333333333333333 
 0 
 0.333333333333333
```

So, no, there is no problem using that function on dynamic arrays. Perhaps you had a typo? Alternatively, if there is no inverse (in e.g. in the above example remove the line `M(2,2) = 3`) you do get that error message. If this is an issue, you could use error-handling to trap that error.

Comment: Hi john:  what would happen if the matrix had no inverse?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Good question -- it does throw that error in that case.

Comment: Thank you John! My mistake was that i was using ReDim M(6,6) instead of ReDim(1 To 6, 1 To 6). Now everything works just fine!